# How can I symbolize credit?

Tags: icon, symbolism

I'm trying to think of a way to graphically represent the idea of credit, as in money owed. Are there any conventional solutions to this?

Comment: Currency sign in red with a negative in front of it.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum not a bad suggestion, but won't work in my case as there is no currency symbol in the country I'm designing for.

Comment: Generic coins/bills in red?

Comment: There actually _is_ such a thing as a [generic international currency symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_%28typography%29), but, well, nobody really uses it. That said, in the absence of a suitable local currency symbol, you _might_ be able to get away with just using the dollar sign; it's pretty well recognized worldwide.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm proud to say that I ''do'' know about the currency symbol! :) I learned about it a few years ago while trying to figure out different currencies in an accounting software. Good point about the dollar sign, I'll consider it.

Comment: Coins in red as Lauren suggested is probably the best option. Every currency has coins.

Comment: Hi Bernk! Unfortunately and it stands, this question would never get an 'ultimate' answer, but generate a brainstorming list instead, something that is not in scope according to our [FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: To be fair, Yisela, we have had very popular questions that fall under this category that are still open. Take this one for example: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/323/new-generation-of-save-icon-that-is-not-a-disk/

Answer (score 0):

When I thought of someone owing me money, the first thing that came to mind was a hand extended forward, palm up. As in, "give me the money." From there, I thought of the bill collector at the door. Not sure if that idea can be converted into whatever you want to do or if that's the kind of connotation you want to carry, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Also, if the target is more accounting-oriented, I remember that debit and credit were literally defined as 'the left and right side of the ledger' in my college accounting class. As someone who knew little about accounting, I thought this was a tremendously meaningless definition, but if you're in that world it makes sense and would be recognizable.